# laravel query builder to add and or condition

Tags: mysql, laravel

Receiving the request in array format

```
[
    [ 
        [ 
        'condition1', 
        'value1',
        ],
        [ 
        'condition2', 
        'value2',
        ],
    ], 
    [ 
    'condition3', 
    'value4',
    ]
]
```

Im trying to build query builder with values1 and values 2 in 'or' condition and value3 in 'and' condition

$result = DB::table('table ')

```
foreach($values as $value){ //
  $result->where(function ($qry) use ($value) { // array 0,1 with and condition
    foreach($value as $val){ // values1 , values2
       $qry->where();
    }

  });

}
```

How to add 'or' condition between the values1 and values2 and then  'and' condition with value3.

Comment: I think that you should have a look at the `whereIn()`. Also, the documnetation is pretty clear on the QB: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: @CornelRaiu my condition1 have many columns and values similarly condition2 and the loop goes next values condition 4... Please let me know how to achieve this in loop,

Comment: it is pretty hard to give advice on stuff like this being blindfolded. You should add some more data to the question as well as some details on your expected results.

Answer (score 4):

Don't need any loop, you need **sub query**, like this :

```
$result = DB::table('table')
   ->where(function($query) use($value1) {
      $query->where('condition1', $value1)
            ->orWhere('condition2', $value1);
   })
   ->where('condition3', $value2)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @STA for the reply but the array will keep going. It is possible to do in loop.

Comment: @Mohan, for array you can use `whereIn` instead of `where` and `orWhereIn` instead of `orWhere`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the condition 1 has multiple columns and values and similar condition 2 . So unable to use whereIn.